# Ctrl + F for paginated table

Tags: php, sql, sorting, filter, html-table

I have a large table that I fill with some data from my database. 
Of course I can't display all rows into my web page because there are too much data. So I have a pagination function to split my data into pages.

I am searching a solution to find the next occurence of something in the table I've on my web page but in all pages.

Basically I want to do a CTRL +F on all pages, how is that possible ? Do you have any links about this ?

Edit : I don't want to filter my table and only see the researched term, I want to see every rows around. It would be like a button previous/next that allow us to go to the next occurence without changing anything else.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want ctrl + F on table ?

Comment: Either hold the whole result-set in memory and search there, or search the database again?

Comment: As I understood your question, You can implement filter function right ?

Comment: Essentially, you want to search for, and jump to, the next occurrence of a keyword, even when that keyword isn't even on the current page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done, but `ctrl-F` won't do it, because this function can only see data that has been loaded onto the current page on the client.

What you want to do is create a custom search feature, which allows you to jump to the next (or previous) occurrence of the chosen keyword. The custom search would run on the server, using the knowledge of the search result set which is paged (on the server) and displayed (page-by-page) on the client.

So, let's say you have 25 pages in your filtered set of data. You are on page 4, and you want to go to the next occurrence of **coolness**. Your custom search identifies that this keyword exists in records 237, 455 and 1140 (as per the current filter) and with a page-size of 50, that means you have a keyword on pages 5, 10 and 23.

Your custom [Next] [Previous] buttons can use the returned page information to jump to pages 5, 10 and 23 accordingly.

You would not need to keep more than one page of data on the client, if you do the paging (and keyword-searching) on the server, and you would only need to do this custom search once each time the main search filter changed, or each time the user wanted to change the keyword they were looking for.

Comment: Yes that is exactly want I want. If you have any ressources about this do not hesitate to tell me

Comment: I don't know if anything like this exists. I could definitely create a feature to do this, and it would be a fun exercise. However, it would currently be a lower priority than my full-time job.